# Node Docker Container - Pulls from Git Repo for Node App Source Upon Running

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, dockerhub, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker image that is generic and can be used with all my Node applications. My current docker image and logic pulls the source for the app from the specified Git repo received as a command line arg when running the docker image.  Here is the code for the docker file and entrypoint logic:

Dockerfile:

```
# Generic Docker Image for Running Node app from Git Repository
FROM    node:0.10.33-slim
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Add script to pull Node app from Git and run the app
COPY docker-node-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["--help"]
```

Entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Run the command passed in if it isn't to start a node app
if [ "$1" != 'node-server' ]; then
   exec "$@"
fi
# Logic for pulling the node app and starting it
cd /usr/src
# try to remove the repo if it already exists
rm -rf node-app; true
echo "Pulling Node app's source from $2"
git clone $2 node-app
cd node-app
# Check if we should be running a specific commit from the git repo
if [ ! -z "$3" ]; then
  echo "Changing to commit $3"
  git checkout $3
fi
npm install
echo "Starting the app"
exec node .
```

I know Docker recommends using the exec command to not have your process killed via SIGKILL when the container is stopped and it times out?  Are there any concerns about the git clone command and npm install command running when the container is stopped as I am not using exec?  Is there a way to fix this in my entrypoint script?

Comment: Please ask separate questions rather than one question with multiple sub-questions.

Comment: Done. Anyhelp with the only question I have kept would be appreciated